# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in more html files

Tags: javascript, html

Есть несколько html файлов и один скрипт. При подключении скрипта перед закрывающим тегом `body` ко всем страницам он перестаёт видеть DOM элементы, если закомментить функции, где есть данные DOM элементы, то скрипт продолжает работать. Например, если в файле `phrase.html`, закомментить все функции которые привязаны к DOM элементам в `image.html`, то функции для `phrase.html` заработают.

```js
import {handleCopyText, submitPhraseResult, loadImageSubmit, hoverFirstImageError, hoverSecondImageError, unhoverImageError, 
    popupOpen, popupClose} from './utils.js';

// Quote
const userInput = document.querySelector('#user-input');
const phraseResult = document.querySelector('.qoute__phrase-result');
const phraseButton = document.querySelector('.quote__form-button');
const phrase = document.querySelector('.quote__phrase-name');
const copyInput = document.querySelector('#user-input-copy');
const copyButton = document.querySelector('.quote__form-button-copy');
// Quote

// Image
const imageContainer = document.querySelector('.image__load');
const firstImageError = document.querySelector('#first-error');
const secondImageError = document.querySelector('#second-error');
const imageErrors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.image__load-violations'));
const imageButtonLoad = document.querySelector('.image__form-button');
const loadText = document.querySelector('.image__load-text');

const firstText = document.querySelector('#first-text');
const secondText = document.querySelector('#second-text');

const imagePunishment = document.querySelector('.image__result')

// Image

// Popup
const popupOpenButton = document.querySelector('.header__login-button');
const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
const popupCloseButon = popup.querySelector('.popup__exit-button');
// Popup

export {userInput, phraseResult, phrase, copyInput, imageContainer, loadText, imageErrors, firstImageError, 
    secondImageError, firstText, secondText, popup, imagePunishment};



phraseButton.addEventListener('click', submitPhraseResult);

copyButton.addEventListener("click", handleCopyText);

imageButtonLoad.addEventListener('click', loadImageSubmit);

firstImageError.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverFirstImageError);
secondImageError.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverSecondImageError);

firstImageError.addEventListener('mouseout', unhoverImageError);
secondImageError.addEventListener('mouseout', unhoverImageError);

popupOpenButton.addEventListener('click', popupOpen);
popupCloseButon.addEventListener('click', popupClose);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./pages/index.css" /> 
    <title>Hakaton 2020</title>
</head>
<body class="page">

    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__logo-and-menu-wrap">
          <a href="./index.html" class="header__logo">
            <p>logo</p>
          </a>
          <ul class="menu menu_place_header">
            <li class="menu__list"><a class="menu__link" href="quote.html">Проверить цитату</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list"><a class="menu__link" href="image.html">Проверить картинку</a></li>
            <li class="menu__list"><a class="menu__link" href="text.html">Проверить текст</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="header__login-button">Войти/зарегистрироваться</button>
      </header>

    <section class="quote">
    <h1 class="qoute__title">Загрузите изображение - мы проверим её на нарушение</h1>
    <div class="image__form-box">
        <!-- <form class="image__form" name="image-load-form" method="POST" id="image-load-form"> -->
            <div class="image__load">
                <p class="image__load-text">Перенесите сюда изображение для проверки</p>
                <div class="image__load-violations" id="first-error">
                    <p class="image__load-violations-text" id="first-text"></p>
                </div>
                <div class="image__load-violations " id="second-error">
                    <p class="image__load-violations-text" id="second-text"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="image__form-button" type="submit" >Загрузить изображение</button>
            <!-- <fieldset class="image__form-set">
            <label class="image__form-field">
            <input class="image__form-input" id="user-input" name="user-input" type="text" placeholder="Сформулируйте вашу мысль"></input>
            <button class="quote__form-button" type="submit" >Подобрать цитату</button>
            </label>
            </fieldset> -->
        <!-- </form> -->
           </div>
        <div class="image__result">
            <h2 class="image__load-title">Если вы используете это изображение в публикации вам грозит</h2>
            <div class="image__punishment">
            <p class="image__punishment-text">Вам грозит<br>
            От 1 до 5 лет лишений свободы на основании УК РФ Статья 319. Оскорбление представителя власти</p>
            <img class="image__punishment-image"  src="./images/Власть.png" alt="Фото"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="image__text">
            Мы живём в мире цензуры, постоянной слежки и ощущения опасности. Что большой брат наблюдает за нами и любой проступок 
            будет караться. Поэтому мы дорожим вашей безопасностью, и оказанным доверием. Мы не храним никаких ваших персональных 
            данных: 
            <br>- IP адрес удаляется каждый час;
            <br>- Кэш сайта стирается после вашего посещения;
            <br>- Для регистрации в системе мы используем seed-фразу. Ваши личные данные не используются.
        </p>
 
    </section>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p>Подвал</p>
      </footer>

      <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup__container">
          <button type="button" aria-label="Close_popup" class="popup__exit-button"></button>
          <form name="popup_form-enter" class="popup__form">
            <p class="popup__input-descr">Войти с помощью секретной фразы</p>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="popup-secret-phrase-input" 
              minlength="2" 
              maxlength="40" 
              class="popup__input popup__input_type_phrase" 
              required >
    
            <button 
              name="popup_form-enter-button" 
              type="submit" 
              class="popup__submit-button">
              Войти
            </button>
          </form>
    
          <form name="popup_form-generate" class="popup__form">
            <p class="popup__input-descr">Создать новую секретную фразу</p>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="popup-phrase-generate-input" 
              minlength="2" 
              maxlength="40"
              class="popup__input popup__input_type_generate" 
              required >
    
            <button 
              name="popup_form-generate-button" 
              type="submit" 
              class="popup__submit-button">
              Сгенерировать
            </button>
          </form>
          <article class="popup__article">
            Секретная фраза это ваш логин в нашей системе. 
            Сохраните его если планируете обращаться к истории ваших
             обращений и если вам понадобятся дополнительные услуги.
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script type="module" src="./scripts/sctipt.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

[image: сама Ошибка]

[image: Если закоментить функции]

Comment: Может Вам приложить код скрипта и страницы, чтобы вам могли помочь?

Comment: По всей видимости он "не видит DOM элементы", потому что на странице нет интересующих его элементов?

Comment: https://codepen.io/niceguyg/pen/abmyWvM

Comment: Вот я тут добавил один из файлов и script.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
phraseButton && phraseButton.addEventListener('click', submitPhraseResult);
...
```

или

```
if (phraseButton) phraseButton.addEventListener('click', submitPhraseResult);
...
```

Comment: А что это даёт? Я не совсем понимаю)

Comment: @Ramil Это дает то, что Вам нужно - проверку существования элемента перед вызовом `addEventListener`.

Comment: Понял, ошибка исчезла, спасибо Вам)

Comment: @Ramil Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.